# Why should I use autorelease in this scenario?

Tags: ios, memory-management, autorelease, reference-counting

I'm an objective-c newbie and I just can't understand why it is a bad idea to release object that doesn't belong to me.

Let's say I have this in the method called `Europe`

```
//initForStringTheory is a class init method;
Collider *LHC = [Collider initForStringTheory]; 

//Colliders is a NSMutableArray
[Colliders addObject: LHC]  

[LHC release]
```

I'm adviced not to release `LHC` in `Europe` as `Europe` does not own `LHC`, it only has a pointer to it. And therefore I should make good use of the autorelease pool and do

```
//newCollider is a pointer for the newly created instance in initForStringTheory
return [newCollider autorelease];
```

in `initForStringTheory`. But why?

Doesn't the pointer in `Europe` points to the instance too? Why can't I just release `LHC` in `Europe` instead of returning a autoreleasing `newCollider` in the init method?

Comment: There really isn't much of a reason to use manual memory management now that ARC is available.

Comment: @dandan78 Manual Memory Management is important to understand. Even if ARC does this for you. Core Foundation is such an example. It requires to understand MMM for example. And ARC does not manage it for you.

Comment: @flex Point conceded. However, I think it is probably not a good idea to use it except when you have to because it introduces the possibility of memory leaks.

Comment: @dandan78 Also ARC is not free from leaks. It's quite common to have cycles. Anyway, I really suggest to *understand* those concepts to have a deeper understanding of how ARC works. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all a question of what `initForStringTheory` returns - if this is a convenience initialization method such as `[NSArray arrayWithObjects...]` or `[NSString stringWithFormat...]`, it creates an **autoreleased** instance that you do not need to release after adding it to your collection. However, if this is an initialization that returns an initialized **non-autoreleased** instance, it is your responsibility to release the local instance definition in your method right after adding it to the collection.

The retain count of the object is incremented by 1 when it is added, so you don't want it to be 2 because you haven't released/autoreleased it after instantiation (would result in a **memory leak** because the object will never become deallocated, even when it's out of the array).

Read this:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html

Comment: So the reason why I shouldn't release object that doesn't belong to me in my scenario is because making the retain count of an object to be 2 results in memory leak?

Comment: No, the reason not to release it is that it's not yours to release - it's been autoreleased by the initializer and it's yours to use but you don't need (and shouldn't) release it. In this screnario we're talking about a double release.

Comment: So if it is an initialization that returns an initialized non-autoreleased instance, I can release the object even if it doesn't belong to me (as long as I don't make the retain count to be 2)?

Comment: It does belong to you - you've called an initialization method that returns an object that is now retained by you, meaning it's your responsibility to release it.

Comment: sorry for the unclear expression, my question is actually very simple, why can't I release it in a method that does not own it?

Comment: It's fine, I'll try to help. I just need to understand what you mean when you say "a method that does not own it"

Comment: Thanks. I was being confused with the concept of reference-counting back then but after going through some articles in the Apple developer site I'm able grasp the whole picture now. So, problem solved :)

Comment: "it creates an autoreleased instance" it's doesn't have to be autoreleased. it's just not retained for you

Comment: Here's a great guide that will help you understand the meaning of ownership in terms of memory management: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html

Answer (score 1):

Stavash basically covered that whether you release it depends on whether the method returned a retaining instance or not.

However, you shouldn't really ever need to know what a method does in order to use memory management correctly. Cocoa MRC memory management follows rules on what methods do based on the *name of the method*. According to the rules, methods whose names start with `alloc`, `retain`, `new`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy` return a retained instance, and the caller are responsible for releasing it. Methods with all other names return a non-retained instance, and the caller should not release it.

So, assuming (of course, that's a big assumption) that `initForStringTheory` follows the rules properly, it should not return a retaining instance (that does not mean it is necessarily `autorelease`d; it may be retained by something else and simply returned directly to you).

Another part of the problem is that it is highly unconventional to have a *class method* named `init...`. Generally, instance methods starting with `init` are constructors, which are run immediately on the result of an `alloc` which created the instance. So what the hell does a class method named `init...` do? Also, by convention there is a special rule for `init` methods, that it "consumes" the retained instance returned by `alloc`, and returns a (not necessarily the same) retained instance. But how would that apply to this case, where it is called on a class? Would it "consume" a retain count on the class object (which does nothing), and then return a retained instance? Nobody knows.

So in conclusion, this code really needs to be re-written. Definitely do not have class methods named `init...`. And make sure that all the methods you write have memory management behaviors that correctly follow the rules, based on their names.

Comment: +1 for your explanation. Nice. I would modify the term *constructors* with *initializers*. But the final concept it's the same. ;)